# artisan not working in laravel 5.2 returning [ErrorException]

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm getting problem when trying to execute php artisan "command". Does not matter the command.

For example, executing the command:

```
php artisan make:controller TestController
```

I have got the following result

```
  [ErrorException]
  Undefined variable: ths
```

What I have tried to do?

I have tried to update/install composer

```
composer update
composer install
composer dump-autoload
```

It's causing me a lot of problem for example I can't execute my migration in another words I can't take the next steps.

Would be great if someone has some idea how to fix that.

Thank's a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means that somewhere you have a class with `$ths` variable and it's not related to commands. I think you wrote some code and used `$ths` instead of `$this`. Check all last changes (custom commands, facades, service providers etc). Just fix it and commands will work again.

If you can't find `$ths` in your code, check Laravel error logs for extra info.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest finding this in your code. If you use Sublime Text press:

The keyboard shortcut is Ctrl⇧+F on non-Mac (regular) keyboards, and ⌘⇧+F on a Mac.

And put `$this` on this variable instead of `$ths`